# What is the difference between setting DEVELOPER_DIR and using xcode-select?

Tags: xcode

Setting the DEVELOPER_DIR variable takes precedence over using xcode-select but I'm curious, what is the difference between the two?

Which should I use if I'm running multiple Xcode versions on the same machine?

Answer (score 15):

xcode-select will always take effect system-wide. DEVELOPER_DIR can be used in a per-shell environment. DEVELOPER_DIR thus allows you to have more precise control over Xcode version on a per-project basis in for example a continous integration setup.

E.g. imagine that you would have each project changing version via xcode-select, then if two separate projects builds run concurrently then you would likely have problems. But if you instead setup each project / CI environment to export it's own DEVELOPER_DIR, then concurrent builds won't be an issue.

Comment: What if I want to run multiple xcodebuild under single Xcode? Is it possible by changing and other conf?

Comment: Actually this is the opposite of what I've noticed. I just upgraded to Xcode 9.3 and re-downloaded Xcode 9.2 and I need to flip between the two to test some things on my frameworks. I found that unsetting `DEVELOPER_DIR` and using `xcode-select` was only setting that Xcode for that shell. Whereas `DEVELOPER_DIR` kept me stuck on one version throughout.