# Manage Xcode Command Line Tools version for each user

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using two different Xcode version with 2 different Command Line Tools version as well. On my Mac I have one user for development and the other one as a Jenkins slave and, for some reasons that don't belong here, I need to use different Command Line Tools version for each user. The thing is that every time I select a new Build Tools version, changes apply to all users.

Is there any way to select Build Tools version for EACH user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way to solve yout problem would be using the environment var $DEVELOPER_DIR, as you can see here:

[What is the difference between setting DEVELOPER_DIR and using xcode-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527838/what-is-the-difference-between-setting-developer-dir-and-using-xcode-select)

You can try to use this wrapper. It allows you to execute xcode-select without sudo permissions:

https://github.com/detroit-labs/safe-xcode-select

Alternatively, if that doesn't work for you, you can try allowing xcode-select to be executed with sudo permissions but without the password:

https://encyclopediaofdaniel.com/blog/sudo-without-a-password/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Find your toolchain name (say `swift-dev`) and then run:

`export TOOLCHAINS=swift-dev`

on login?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer but I think I need a bit more of information in order to be able to fix my problem. Can you please elaborate it a bir more? Thanks in advance!